# Connecting Difference Amplifier to High Impedence Sensor

Tags: sensor, analog, high-impedance

I have a high impedance differential sensor (stable 600k impedance Rth, 10mV signal, Fout=1kHz). I need to amplify this signal to about 1V (40dB gain). Due to layout/system constraints only the [TLV9061](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv9061.pdf) OpAmp stage can be used. Any suggestions on what topology would enable this? The problem I run into is that any difference amplifier or transimpedence amplifier needs feedback resistors that are unreasonably high (10s or 100s of Megohm) for a real world implementation.

I was looking into T-Network solutions as in this [thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333055/op-amp-with-t-network-feedback) but it seems they suffer from high current noise.

Looking for any advice on other topologies to explore or methods to consider. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: (1) What's the nature of the sensor?  (2) Is it connected through a cable?  Or, is it mounted on the same PCB as the amplifier?  (3) Is using an instrumentation amplifier an option for you?  If not, why not?

Comment: Sample rate or bandwidth? Is there a reason you cannot use an integrator? The (-) terminal of your opamp may need a guard ring.

Comment: There are ICs which pack 4 OpAmps into one small footprint, including feedback resistors. So the layout constraints can't be an excuse. Any so-called "instrumental amplifiers" should do the job, especially at 1 kHz range.

Comment: Single supply? Needs Vcc/2 ref not 0V . Long cable? Needs better CM balanced impedance on Vin(+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the op-amp in non-inverting mode: -

[image]

The impedance it presents to the transducer is giga ohms and the feedback resistors are isolated from the transducer hence don't need to be mega ohms; they just need to have the correct ratio i.e. 99:1 to give 100x amplification.

For the TLV9061, be aware that if used in single supply rail applications the output won't quite get down to 0 volts.

Comment: Yes, I have come to this conclusion as well so focusing on this implementation. With dual rail supply. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If by "single op amp" you mean you can accept an 8-pin package, an [AD621R](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD621.pdf) in 8-pin SOIC will give you a gain of 100 with no external components and extremely high input impedance.

Comment: +1 Yep, modern silicon technology makes real wonders!

Comment: Sorry updated description due to size constraints have to use X2SON package