# Resistive T-network

Tags: feedback, gain

Can someone explain to me why this negative feedback resistive T-network simulates a 10M ohm resistance ?

The overall closed loop gain is -100 because 10M/100k = 100.

[image]

Comment: Oh... another Falstad user :)

Comment: Easy to use and comprehensive :) Sadly it fails at complex design

Comment: Simple calculation: use star-triangle transformation.

Comment: Here you find the answer https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333055/op-amp-with-t-network-feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple way to look at is that the 100 kohm resistor from the op-amp output and the 1 kohm resistor form a 100:1 potential divider (approximately). This means that the op-amp gain is 100 times higher than it would be if there was only a single 100 kohm resistor as the feedback element. This makes the 100 kohm resistor, in effect, 100 times in value or 10 Mohm.

If you need more understanding, take a look at this picture: -

[image]

You know that the gain at the op-amp output is -100 and it shouldn't be a surprise to find that the gain at the junction of the 9.9 Mohm and the 100 kohm (in the feedback path) is -1.

The 9.9 Mohm resistor is (approximately) equivalent to the 100 k / 1 k potential divider in the original circuit and gives approximately the same result as this: -

[image]

Of course you could convert the op-amp output to a current source in parallel with a 100 kohm resistor and note that the 100 kohm then becomes in parallel with the 1 kohm resistor. Then you could convert back to a voltage source (about 100 times smaller than the original op-amp output) in series with a 0.99 kohm resistor but you'd come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! I didn't understood at the beginning but now is clear.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNrMcE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If we assume the op-amp is not limited by either the negative or positive supplies (not clipping), then `V+ = V-`

`V+ = V- = 0V`

`Ir1 = (Vin - V-)/R1`

`Ir2 = (V- - V1)/R2`

`Ir2 = (-V1)/R2`

`Ir3 = (Vout - V1) / R3`

`Ir4 = Ir2 + Ir3`

`Ir4 = V1 / R4`

Those are what can immediately gathered from our circuit.

Application of basic series parallel circuit with `R2`, `R3`, `R4`

`V1 = Vout * (1/(1/R2 + 1/R4)) / (R3 + 1/(1/R2 + 1/R4))`

`V1 = Vout * (R2 + R4)/(R2*R4) / (R3 + (R2 + R4)/(R2*R4))`

`V1 = Vout * (101k/100M) / (100k + (101k/100M))`

`V1 = Vout * (101k/100M) / (100k*100M/100M + (101k/100M))`

`V1 = Vout * (101k/100M) / (100k*100M + 101k/100M)`

`V1 = Vout * (101k) / (100k*100M + 101k)`

`V1 = Vout * (101,000) / (100,000 * 100,000,000 + 101,000)`

`V1 = Vout * (101,000) / (10,000,000,101,000)`

`V1 = Vout * (101) / (10,000,000,101)`

We calculated a value for `V1` based in `Vout`.

`Ir1 = Ir2`

`(Vin - V-)/R1 = (V- - V1)/R2`

`(Vin)/R1 = (-V1)/R2`

`(Vin)/R1 = (-Vout * (101) / (10,000,000,101))/R2`

`(Vin*R2)/R1 = (-Vout * (101) / (10,000,000,101))`

`Vin = (-Vout * (101) / (10,000,000,101))`

`-Vin * 10,000,000,101 / 101 = Vout`

Standard form is `Vout = -Vin * R2 / R1`

Multiplying by 100k/101 (a factor of about 990.09), the equivalent `R2` is `9.9 gigaohms`

If this simulates a 10M feedback resistor then I have miscalculated somewhere

Answer (score 0):

assume that -ve terminal of opamp is virtually grounded. From output the resistance looking in is approx 110k ignoring the 100k in parallel to the 10k. Now what happens to the current that flows through the 100k? it sees two paths one which is 10x resistive and one which is 1x resistive at the junction. Obviously this results in only the 10% of the current to flow through the 100k and rest 90% through 10k. So you have created a current that flows through the last 100k that is 10 times smaller than what flows through a 110k resistor. or equivalently a 1M resistor.