# I am having a hard time analyzing this type of circuit. How do I get the voltage gain?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

[image]

I am trying to solve these questions  but I can't even do the first step. What's a good method to deal with this type of circuit?

Comment: The wye-delta transform might be useful here.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389153/resistive-t-network

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resistive T-network](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389153/resistive-t-network)

Answer (score 2):

**Hopefully helpful hint**

> *How do I get the voltage gain?*

I usually start this way: -

[image]

- Because the op-amp has a virtual ground, the loading effect at \$\color{red}{V_X}\$ is due to R3 in parallel with R2
- I can then split things up and put an imaginary buffer amp in the feed to R2
- So now you can calculate the gain \$\color{blue}{V_Y} / V_{IN}\$
- It's just \$-R_2/R_1\$
- Then figure out how much the other resistors attenuate the signal at \$\color{red}{V_X}\$ and, the true gain \$(V_{OUT} / V_{IN})\$, can be easily calculated.