# Inverting Op Amp Finding resistor value of voltage divider

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider

****A small clarification V_2 = -100V_1****

I don't think my analysis is correct since I ended up with R1 as a denominator.

[image]

Comment: The most simple and direct calculation: Application of the Star-Delta transformation.

Comment: whats the use of splitting the feedback resistor and connect the load Resistor there?

Comment: That is called a T-network.  Maybe this answer can help? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333055/op-amp-with-t-network-feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit (assuming an ideal [opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier)):

[image: schematic]

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_4\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_4
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, using an [ideal opamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op_amps), we know that:

$$\text{V}_+=\text{V}_-=\text{V}_1=0$$

So we can rewrite equation \$(3)\$ as follows:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\displaystyle0-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\displaystyle0-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_2-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{V}_3\$:

$$\text{V}_3=-\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{R}_3\text{R}_4+\text{R}_2\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)\right)}{\text{R}_1\text{R}_3}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=V1 = 0;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2, I3 == I2 + I4, I3 == I1 + I4, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, 
   I2 == (V1 - V2)/R2, I3 == V2/R3, I4 == (V3 - V2)/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, 
   I4, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> Vi/R1, I2 -> Vi/R1, I3 -> -((R2 Vi)/(R1 R3)), 
  I4 -> -(((R2 + R3) Vi)/(R1 R3)), V2 -> -((R2 Vi)/R1), 
  V3 -> -(((R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)) Vi)/(R1 R3))}}
```

---

Applying this to your circuit, we know that \$\text{R}_1=\text{R}_2=\text{R}_4=10000\space\Omega\$ and we want to find \$\text{R}_3\$ such that \$\text{V}_3=-100\text{V}_\text{i}\$. So, using \$(5)\$, we can write:

$$-100\text{V}_\text{i}=-\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}\left(\text{R}_3\cdot10000+10000\left(\text{R}_3+10000\right)\right)}{10000\cdot\text{R}_3}\tag6$$

Because we know that \$\text{V}_\text{i}\ne0\$ we can divide both sides by \$\text{V}_\text{i}\$, end we end up with:

$$-100=-\frac{\left(\text{R}_3\cdot10000+10000\left(\text{R}_3+10000\right)\right)}{10000\cdot\text{R}_3}\tag7$$

And find:

$$\text{R}_3=\frac{5000}{49}\approx102.041\space\Omega\tag8$$

Where I used Mathematica-code again:

```
In[2]:=R1 = 10000;
R2 = 10000;
R4 = 10000;
V3 = -100*Vi;
FullSimplify[Solve[V3 == -(((R3 R4 + R2 (R3 + R4)) Vi)/(R1 R3)), R3]]

Out[2]={{R3 -> 5000/49}}

In[3]:=N[{{R3 -> 5000/49}}]

Out[3]={{R3 -> 102.041}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The practical thinking engineer would immediately see in this configuration an inverting amplifier with a voltage divider included in the output. Usually R2 >> R3||R4 (i.e., the voltage divider has low output resistance); so the gain is simply -R2/R1 X (R3 + R4)/R3.

The name "T network" is misleading and it prevents understanding. It is much better to think of the circuit as a "twice-disturbed operational amplifier with negative feedback" (here these disturbances are useful). The first "disturbance" is caused by the R1-R2 summing circuit; the second "disturbance" is caused by the R3-R4 voltage divider. The two devices are cascaded attenuators that form the feedback network.

The "golden rule" is: if you take the output after a disturbance, it will be eliminated by the op-amp with excessive voltage before the disturbance; if you take the output before the disturbance, it will be an amplifying output. This trick is used in all the op-amp amplifying circuits with negative feedback to make a follower (inverter) amplify.

According to these explanations, V1 is "undisturbed output", V2 - "once-disturbed output" and V3 is a "double-disturbed output":) ... and V1 < V2 < V3.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this quickly by finding the Thevenin equivalent voltage in the feedback.

Voltage is Vo * R1/(R1+R4) and resistance is (R4||R1)+R3

Gain to the Thevenin feedback voltage (KCL or inverting amplifier formula)

G' =  \$-\frac{(R_4||R_1) + R_3}{R_2}\$

So gain to the op-amp output is just:

G = \$- \frac{R_1 + R_4}{R_1} \cdot \frac{(R_4||R_1) + R_3}{R_2}\$

Given R2=R3=R4 = 10K\$\Omega\$ we can solve this numerically to get
R1 ~= 102.0408171668\$\Omega\$ for G= -100.0