# In the circuit below, assume ideal op-amp, find Vout?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

Assuming ideal op-amp, I have this question that asks to find Vout:

[image: Circuit Question]

My solution seems to be wrong since it is an inverting op-amp, so I believe Vout must be negative.
Can anyone check please?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mistake is in V2K calculation. Since you have considered that
Vout = Vx + V2K,

You should take V2k = -4V

So, Vout becomes -5V

[image]

Comment: Oh I missed the current direction, Thanks mate.

Answer (score 3):

The equation for the Vx nodes currents should look like this:

\$0=\frac{V_{-}-V_X}{I_2}-\frac{V_X-V_{out}}{I_4}+\frac{V_X}{I_3}\$

I1 and I2 are equal because of the high impedance of the input pin of an ideal opamp. The pins do not sink current

Answer (score 3):

The answer can also be obtained with almost no calculations, just knowing the properties of feedback op-amp circuits:

1. On the left we see an inverting amplifier with two identical 1k resistors and Vx output voltage. Therefore, Vx = -1 V.
2. However, the op-amp is "disturbed" by a voltage divider (R1 = 1 k||1k and R2 = 2 k) with a gain of 1/5. It is forced to compensate for this "disturbance" (attenuation) by 5x amplification.  Therefore, Vout = -5V.
3. Thus the circuit combines two resistor networks - 1 k + 1 k on the left (of an inverting amplifier) and 1 k + 2 k on the right (of a non-inverting amplifier). So it can be considered as a "doubly-disturbed op-amp".
4. The 2k resistor between the output and ground does not play any role (it just loads the op-amp a bit). It was probably put there for deception.

Here are some more considerations about this odd circuit solution:

1. Typically the resistor between the op-amp output and the inverting input has a relatively high resistance and does not load the voltage divider. Then the analysis becomes even simpler.
2. Because of the configuration of three resistors on the right in the shape of the letter T, the circuit is often called an "inverting amplifier with a T-bridge in the feedback network" but it is not suitable for an intuitive explanation.
3. A general idea for building feedback op-amp circuits can be derived from this particular circuit - *an additional gain can be obtained by additional attenuation in the feedback loop*.

See also a [related answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/523532/61398).