# Problem with parasitic capacitor in feedback path in inverting circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, parasitic-capacitance

I want to meet following conditions:

Gain: 27.74 dB

Input source resistance: 6800 Ohm

Bandwidth: 15Khz (I actually need to have a flat response until 10khz and I do not care about the rest of it)

I used a T resistor network in my feedback path because I did not want to use a Mega Ohm order resistor in my feedback path(because of extra noise)

the following circuit completely works and meets my desire specifications

[image]

and this is the AC simulation.
[image: AC simulation]

However, I read somewhere that there might be a parasitic capacitor between the inverting pin and output of the op-amp. Therefore, when I place a 10pf capacitor in that place, my circuit becomes problematic.

[image]

and this is the AC simulation.
[image]

Is there any way that I can eliminate the effect of this parasitic capacitor?
Or my sole solution is to use 2 op-amp, first stage for increasing input impedance and second stage for the gain?

Comment: I want to ask you this: what made you select a 10 pF capacitor? Where is the justification for this act? What's wrong with using a non-inverting configuration?

Comment: @Andyaka that is just a guess nothing special, but I think that the order is correct. it also is problematic with 1 pf.

Comment: You need to justify 10 pF - do you know how much overlapping copper is needed to produce 10 pF?

Comment: Your information looks utterly convincing. is there any reference which can help me figure out the order of parasitic capacitor?

Comment: You should also take into account that the LM358 will have inverting-input capacitance to ground that will counter this effect. Unfortunately the LM358 is badly specified to give you numbers so this makes it problematic to use. Or use a non-inverting config.

Comment: You have chosen a T-network for the feedback path because of the input resistance. Please note that the input resistance of the inverting combination has no (nearly no) influence on the input resistance.

Comment: @lvw corrected.

Comment: You can approximately compensate Cpara with a capacitor equal to Cpara*Gain across R1. (This ignores R7, you may need to compensate it too for greater accuracy)

Comment: @user_1818839. is there any solution for high impedance input source?

Comment: It sounds like ["These T-networks actually generate higher current noise (iN) and the voltage divider at the output multiplies input offset voltage, drift, and amplifier voltage noise by the ratio of 1+RT/RG."](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333055/op-amp-with-t-network-feedback), the same for the parasitic and input variables. I would invite @jonk for the answer.

Comment: my gain is about 24.4 which gives me 27.74 dB gain. I do not care about bandwidth. I just want a flat response until 10 khz

Comment: @SeAlGhz, sorry, my mistake. :)